# Custom Request Validator in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5.1

I just want to validate API requests using laravel custom Request Handler. For this I have created a RegisterRequest, with the following content.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Api\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class RegisterRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

And, I want it to use in AuthController as:

```
use App\Http\Requests\Api\Auth\RegisterRequest;

    public function postRegister(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

But, neither the validation nor the request parameters are shown in the respose. 
All the routing are working fine, but the query paremeters are empty. Any help will be appriciated.

> Version: Laravel: 5.1

**I want to let laravel handle all request parameters and say API whether the request is made successful or with errors.**

Comment: You request does not even reach the controller method, so you can't dd anything ;D

Answer (score 0):

Your `authorize` method should return true. If it is false , `RegisterRequest` will return forbidden because you are not authorize to use this  `RegisterRequest` class . So, change your `authorize` method from `RegisterRequest` to this :

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

**Edit** : 
If you want to reply the error message in your way you can override the response method in `RegisterRequest` method like this :

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    return \Response::json($errors);
}
```

Comment: I have changed it to false to force error response to api end.

Comment: If the authorize method returns false, a HTTP response with a 403 status code will automatically be returned and your controller method will not execute.  For more info check this  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: And Laravel will automatically check if the request is ajax and returns the corresponding response right ? No any response are returned from the request attempt.